# Collection View didSelectItemAtIndexPath segue

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm struggling for a long time of this problem.

The reason was I had Collection `delegate` & `datasource` under the "`CollectionView`" not "`CollectionView Controller`" because I embedded one `collectionView` in the one of `TableView` Cell

but when I want to set up the

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
{
}
```

This is my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString * Cell;
if (indexPath.section==0)
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            Cell = @"MoviesIntro";
            break;
        case 1:
            Cell = @"影片介紹";
            break;
        case 2:
            Cell = @"Moviesrelative";


            default:
            break;
    }
}
　
UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cell];
}

switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
    {

    }
    break;
    case 1:
    {

    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {

        Tony=(CollectionView*)[cell viewWithTag:741];
        Tony.pageImages =imagearray;
        [Tony reloadData];

    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
    return cell;
```

}

Here is CollectionView.m Code

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    self.pic_url=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pic_url"];
    self.name_zh=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name_zh"];
    self.name_en=[comment[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name_en"];
    self.intro=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"short_Intro"];
    self._id=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"_id"];
    self.trailer=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"trailer"];
    self.movieTime=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"movieTime"];
    self.picH_url=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"picH_url"];
    self.category=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"category"];
    self.director=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"director"];
    self.actor=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"actor"];
    self.language=[comment[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"language"];
    self.MyList=false;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

}

Tony is Collection view.h/m files. pageImages is NSMutableArray on the Tony.h files.

to go to other view controller, property not found on object  so I don't even know what can i do is anyone have good idea？？

Comment: Can you add the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set add a `delegate` variable of your `UITableViewCell` and a delegate method like:

```
- (void) pushToViewController;
```

Then in `YourTableViewCell.m` file collectionView delegate methods add:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *){
   [delegate pushToViewController];
}
```

And "tableView Controller"should be the delegate of your `tableViewCell`, in the controller of `UITableView` :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   YourTableViewCell *cell = ...
   cell.delegate = self;
}
- (void) pushToViewController {
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: i'm a rookies Ios programmer and i will try understand how could i build delegate by own ,thanks a lot ~~

Comment: one more question "YourTableViewCell *cell = ..." what should i add after cell??

Comment: Seems your code works fine. This question is too basic, just google a uitableView tutorial might help. Good luck.

Comment: i solved it and i know it's basic question as well because i google it .Thanks^^

Answer (score 0):

William Hu's suggestion will work.

In general you should not let your UI items implement their own delegates and data sources. It works but breaks the MVC pattern. Instead of that I'd use some custom UICollectionView to hold some reference to the row of the table to which it belongs. You could even 'abuse' the tag property for that (which I personally don't like but is is quite a common pattern) without the need to subclass UICollectionView.

Your UITableViewController can implement the datasource and delegate for the collection views too. On each call of any delegate method a reference to the very collectionView is handed into the method so that you can get the row of the table from there (which you have to set in the table view's cellForRowAtIndexPath of course) and go from there.

Therefore I'd rather suggest re-factoring your code and stick to the MVC pattern.

Comment: actually, i had same thinking but i don't know how to do it (even though i search many information for a while) .Do you had some Web site to talk about this way ,anyway thank you your suggestion~~~~